# How to create custom forms to filter views results in Drupalgap

Tags: views, javascript

I want to build a views page where user searches for a text (without auto-complete) by entering query in a text box and clicking a button on drupalgap, and I want to have flag links on the results
On the documentation page of drupalgap views exposed filters, http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Views_Exposed_Filters "building your own forms and constructing own URL parameters" is mentioned but there is no example of that. Is there any example/tutorial of usage like that?
Thanks in advance,

Update: 
This is the function that I define my form:

```
function form_custom_form(form, form_state) {
      try {
        form.elements['name'] = {
          type: 'textfield',
          title: 'Kart No',
          required: true
        };
        form.elements['submit'] = {
          type: 'submit',
          value: 'Ara'
        };
        form.elements['my_markup'] = {
          markup: '<ul id="arac_getir2_view" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow"></ul>'
        };
        return form;
      }
      catch (error) { console.log('my_module_custom_form - ' + error); }
    }
```

This is the code which works:

```
function form_custom_form_submit(form, form_state) {
  form_value = form_state.values['name'];
  form.elements['my_markup'] = {
    markup: '<ul id="arac_getir2_view" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow"></ul>'
  };
  arac_getir2_pageshow();
}
/*catch (error) { console.log('form_custom_form_submit - ' + error); }*/

function arac_getir2_pageshow() {
  var path_to_view = 'arac_getir';
  views_datasource_get_view_result(path_to_view, {
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.nodes.length > 0) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data.nodes, function(index, object){
          var node = object.node;
          items.push(
            l(node.title, '#') +  
            flag_quick_link(
                    'ara_getir', // The flag's machine name.
                    'node', // The entity type.
                    node.nid, // The entity id.
                    parseInt(node.flagged) ? true : false // The current flag status.
                    )
            );
        });
        console.log(items);
        drupalgap_item_list_populate('#arac_getir2_view', items);

      }
    }
  });
}
```

This is the one which does not:

```
  function form_custom_form_submit(form, form_state) {
    form_value = form_state.values['name'];
    arac_getir_page();
  }

  function arac_getir_page() {
    try {
      var content = {};
      content['arac_list'] = {
        theme: 'view',
        format: 'ul',
        format_attributes: {
          /*'data-inset': 'true',*/
          'data-split-icon': 'star' /*the icon to use for the flag button */
        },
        path: 'arac_getir', /* the path to the view in Drupal */
        row_callback: 'arac_getir_list_row',
        empty_callback: 'arac_getir_list_empty',
        attributes: {
          id: 'arac_getir_view',
          'data-filter': 'true',
        }
      };
      return content;
    }
    catch (error) { console.log('arac_getir_page - ' + error); }
  }

  /**
   * The row callback to render a single row.
   */
   function arac_getir_list_row(view, row) {
    try {
      return l(row.title, 'node/' + row.nid) + row.field_kart_no + 
      flag_quick_link(
        'ara_getir',
        'node',
        row.nid,
        parseInt(row.flagged) ? true : false
        );
    }
    catch (error) { console.log('arac_getir_list_row - ' + error); }
  }

  /**
   *
   */
   function arac_getir_list_empty(view) {
    try {
      return t('Kart bulunamadı');
    }
    catch (error) { console.log('arac_getir_list_empty - ' + error); }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create a custom form: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Forms/Creating_a_Custom_Form

Then in its submit handler build a Views Render Array and inject it into a waiting div placeholder element (markup widget) on the form:

http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Displaying_a_View/Views_Render_Array
http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Forms/Form_Elements/Element_Markup

Or have the submit handler go to a page with arguments: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Pages/Page_Arguments

Then that's page's `page_callback` could build a Views Render Array and use the search string as a contextual filter to the View.

Comment: I couldn't have the submit handler render the views by: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Displaying_a_View/Views_Render_Array but can have it rendered by using:
http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Displaying_a_View/Manually_Display_View/Views_Results_List 
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question to share your submit handler's code.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I've updated the question, hope it's not vague.